# $A \overrightarrow{X}$ and $B \overrightarrow{X}$ are independent random vectors iif $A \Sigma B^{\prime}=\overrightarrow{0}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

I need to prove that if $\overrightarrow{X} \sim N_{p}(\overrightarrow{\mu}, \Sigma)$ then $A \overrightarrow{X}$ and $B \overrightarrow{X}$ are independent random vectors iif $A \Sigma B^{\prime}=\overrightarrow{0}$

It was suggested that I should consider $\overrightarrow{Y}=\left[\begin{array}{ll}A \overrightarrow{X} & B \overrightarrow{X}\end{array}\right]^{\prime},$ and then calculate $V[\overrightarrow{Y}]$ and the characteristic function of $\overrightarrow{Y}$. But I'm having difficulties connecting all of these concepts for the proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Y_1=AX$ and $Y_2=BX$, then in general:

(I) $E\{Y_1 Y_2^T\}=A\Sigma B^T+A\mu\mu^TB^T$.

For $Y1$ and $Y2$ to be independent, $E\{Y_1 Y_2^T\}=E\{Y_1\}E\{Y_2^T\}$ must hold, i.e.,

(II) $E\{Y_1 Y_2^T\}=E\{AX\}E\{X^T B^T\}=A\mu\mu^TB^T$.

So, (I)=(II) iff $A\Sigma B^T=0$.